# Break out of method call from initialize condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When an instance method is called in this fashion...

```
Foo.new(n).bar
```

Is it possible to prevent `bar` from being fired if `n` matches a certain condition in the `initialize` method?

Example:

```
class Foo

  def initialize(n)
    if n == SOMETHING
      # Break and prevent 'bar' from firing
    end
  end

  def bar
    # Do something
  end

end
```

**EDIT:** Use case: I have about 10 methods in class. I need to check the same condition before any of the methods ever fire. I'd rather not clutter the instance methods with the condition check logic.

**EDIT 2** The class is actually an Event Tracking class that is sending event data to my analytics. The conditions being checked are the IP address and the username, so I don't transmit my own event data in production. The method calls will be peppered throughout the application, where they don't really belong (mixing business logic), so I'm trying to make the footprint as minimal as possible. If I need to check the IP address and user every time, it will get ugly.

Comment: Should these methods raise errors, or should they simply do nothing? Do you think the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) would be a good fit here?

Comment: They should do nothing

Comment: Why not simply delay calling the method until the object has been created and the condition checked?

Comment: @Fred please see my second edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using [`alias_method_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain) (it comes from activesupport) came into my mind.

```
class Foo
  def initialize(n)
    @break_execution = n == SOMETHING
  end

  def bar
    # do something
  end

  def foo
    # do something
  end

  def baz
    # do something
  end

  %w(foo bar baz).each do |method|
    define_method "#{method}_with_break_check" do |*args, &block|
      unless @break_execution
        send("#{method}_without_break_check", *args, &block)
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain method, :break_check
  end
end
```

Comment: Please see me edit... Do you think this is still the best approach if every method in `Foo` requires the condition check and will need an `unless...` statement?

Comment: @mnort9 edited. It's quite criptic, but I don't think if there's any much prettier solution.

Comment: @MarekLipka Does it work, though? I get `ruby.rb:25:in `block in <class:Foo>': undefined method `alias_method_chain' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)`. Oh it's Rails only?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers do you use activesupport? This method is contained in activesupport library, which is a part of Ruby on Rails framework (that's why I put here solution using it, since OP added ruby-on-rails tag).

Comment: @MarekLipka Ah, I ran it in pure Ruby.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the methods array: `Foo.instance_methods(false).each`